# Mounting smb shares on OS X accessible with Microsoft account

Tags: mount, osx, samba

I have a Windows machine which shares a particular directory and only an owner of this directory is able to access it over the network. Owner account is linked to Microsoft account.

I am trying to mount this share from the terminal in OS X (mounting from Finder works OK), but I am having issues, I believe because the account username contains '@' character.

I tried the following:

```
mount -t smbfs '//username%40outlook.com:password@hostname/path' local_dir
mount -t smbfs '//username\@outlook.com:password@hostname/path' local_dir
mount -t smbfs '//"username@outlook.com":password@hostname/path' local_dir
```

First command gives me authentication error (I guess %40 is treated literally), and the other two give me "URL parsing failed". On OS X I can't pass username and password with -o option.

I also tried mounting with `-t cifs` but with that I get the strange output

```
mount: exec */path/to/mount_cifs* local_dir: No such file or directory
```

(note that I can't c/p from OS/X right now so I shorthanded the path to mount_cifs)

Can anyone provide a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution and in the end it was pretty simple, I just couldn't see the forrest for the tree.

Find out the actual username on Windows by going to `Computer Managamenet -> Local Users and Groups -> Users`. Account should be listed there with the real name. Then use this name instead of the Microsoft account one and all should work.

Edit: One other possible way is to use the 'MicrosoftAccounts' as a domain name, and then use the actual Microsoft account username (e-mail).